# jackson ObjectMapper need to serialize a value, and not reture null, but different object, there is different representation

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper

my jackson version is 2.9.3
there is code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    //init objectMapper
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

    //construct map
    Map<String, Object> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    map.put("boolean", "true");
    map.put("number", "123");
    map.put("string", null);
    Map<String, String> map1 = Maps.newHashMap();
    map1.put("a", null);
    map1.put("c", "d");
    map1.put("e", null);
    map.put("object", map1);
    Integer[] a = new Integer[]{null, 2, 3};
    map.put("array", a);

    //construct jsonNode;
    String test = "{\"array\":[null,2,3],\"boolean\":true,\"number\":123,\"object\":{\"a\":null,\"c\":\"d\",\"e\":null},\"string\":null}";
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(test);

    //output
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode));
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map));
}
```

the result is

```
{"array":[null,2,3],"boolean":true,"number":123,"object":{"a":null,"c":"d","e":null},"string":null}
{"number":"123","boolean":"true","array":[null,2,3],"object":{"c":"d"}}
```

to Map type, there doesn't have null, but to JsonNode, there has null.

what happen?

Comment: Where is this `JsonUtils` class being imported from?

Comment: It‘s a my tool class，the function json2map convert a json string to a map, this map is {array=[null, 2, 3], boolean=true, number=123, object={a=null, c=d, e=null}, string=null} @entpnerd

Comment: would you please post the source code for `JsonUtils` to your question?

Comment: sorry, wait for a long time.   I has improve the question

Comment: Basically, I want to run JsonUtils through a debugger. I think that you're missing something because `objectMapperNotContainNull` doesn't compile. Please just upload the `JsonUtils.java` file.

Comment: I recode, there does't have wondering code segment

Comment: sounds good. consider adding your answer for what was happening.